# Is there any way to test the Power Management features like WakeLock on the android emulator?

Tags: android

Is there any way to to emulate the power management features in order to test something like a WakeLock on the android emulator? This would be in case of temporarily being unable to test on a real device and to ease debugging.

Maybe this makes no sense, but I thought it might be worth asking people out there who probably know a lot more about this and can give me a definite NO if that is the case or a YES and guide me as to how.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey, a similar issue arose this week for us. I think I found what it was.

For us, the issue was a setting in the emulator.

Go to:

*Settings -> Applications -> Development -> **Stay awake*** (This way, the screen will never sleep while charging)

I guess in the emulator's case it behaves like it is always charging and therefore the screen never locks even if you change values in: "*Settings -> Display -> Screen timeout*" which is what we were unsuccessfully doing.

Hope that this helps!

Answer (score 0):

WakeLock should work the same way on the emulator as on a hardware device.
maybe if you could be more specific as to what you're trying to test?

Comment: My emulator's screen never times out, maybe there are some settings I need to set that I haven't but the screen always stays on, unlike with a real device where then screen normally dims and then gets turned off requiring the device to require unlocking. Is the emulator supposed to work like this too ? What am I doing wrong ?